# Get MassTransit.RequestTimeoutException when using with Azure Service Bus

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, masstransit

I'm newbie Masstransit, and going to apply the Durable Future and Routing slip pattern with Azure Service Bus.
The web app with a controller as defined below:

```
app.MapPost("/orders/submit", async (SubmitOrderDto submitOrderDto, IRequestClient<SubmitOrder> client, ILogger<Program> logger, CancellationToken cancellationToken) =>
            {
                try
                {
                    Response response = await client.GetResponse<OrderCompleted, OrderFaulted>(new
                    {
                        submitOrderDto.OrderId
                    }, cancellationToken);
                    return response switch
                    {
                        (_, OrderCompleted completed) => Results.Ok(new
                        {
                            completed.OrderId,
                            completed.Status,
                            completed.Created,
                            completed.Completed,
                        }),
                        (_, OrderFaulted faulted) => Results.BadRequest(new
                        {
                            faulted.OrderId,
                            faulted.Description,
                            faulted.Created,
                            faulted.Faulted
                        }),
                        _ => Results.BadRequest()
                    };
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    return Results.Accepted(value:new
                    {
                        submitOrderDto.OrderId, 
                        ex.Message
                    });
                }
            })
            .Produces<OrderCompleted>()
            .Produces<OrderFaulted>(StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest)
            .Produces(StatusCodes.Status202Accepted)
            .ProducesValidationProblem(StatusCodes.Status409Conflict)
            .WithName("SubmitOrder").WithTags("OrderServiceAPI");
```

There're Future, Planner and activities classes.
My expected if there
s the request is submitted then it'll be validated by Activities class then returning faults to client. If it passed validation it could be continue the process.

But I'm getting Masstransit exception as below:

> Timeout waiting for response, RequestId: 40040000-4446-107b-e828-08db2e658cb0
> at MassTransit.Clients.RequestClient`1.GetResponseInternal[T1,T2](SendRequestCallback request, CancellationToken cancellationToken, RequestTimeout timeout, RequestPipeConfiguratorCallback`1 callback) in /_/src/MassTransit/Clients/RequestClient.cs:line 212

If I switch to use the RabbitMq, the request was validated as I expected. But when using with Azure Service Bus it's always has timeout exception as above
In Program, I've inject Masstransit as below and using Masstransit v8 package

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Services.TryAddScoped<IItineraryPlanner<SubmitOrder>, OrderItineraryPlannerAzure>();

builder.Services.AddMassTransit(x =>
{

 // Azure
    x.SetKebabCaseEndpointNameFormatter();
    x.AddServiceBusMessageScheduler();
    x.AddRequestClient<SubmitOrder>();

    //-------------
    x.ApplyCustomMassTransitConfiguration();
    x.AddDelayedMessageScheduler();
    x.AddActivitiesFromNamespaceContaining<OrderActivity>();
    x.AddFuturesFromNamespaceContaining<OrderFuture>();

    x.AddSagaRepository<FutureState>()
        .InMemoryRepository();

    //x.UsingRabbitMq((context, cfg) =>
    //{
    //    cfg.AutoStart = true;
    //    cfg.ApplyCustomBusConfiguration();

    //    cfg.UseDelayedMessageScheduler();
    //    cfg.ConfigureEndpoints(context);
    //});

    x.UsingAzureServiceBus((context, cfg) =>
    {
        using var scope = context.CreateScope();  
 cfg.Host("Endpoint=sb://{connectionString}");

        cfg.UseTimeout(timeoutConfigurator =>
        {
            timeoutConfigurator.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10);
        });
        cfg.PrefetchCount = 100;
        cfg.LockDuration = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
        cfg.MaxConcurrentCalls = 100;
        cfg.MaxDeliveryCount = 5;
        cfg.DefaultMessageTimeToLive = TimeSpan.FromDays(7);
        cfg.AutoStart = true;
        cfg.RequiresSession = true;

        cfg.UseServiceBusMessageScheduler();
        // deploy topology configuration when service starting
        cfg.DeployTopologyOnly = true;
        cfg.UseDelayedMessageScheduler();
        cfg.ConfigureEndpoints(context);
    });
```

I'm thinking I need to create consumer for request client, but I don't know how to define it in Futures pattern. Or do I miss any step?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you're really over-specifying the bus configuration for Azure Service Bus, and in doing so are configuring things that are going to break things.

Remove:

```cs
cfg.RequiresSession = true;
cfg.DeployTopologyOnly = true;
cfg.UseDelayedMessageScheduler();
```

Also, above that, remove:

```cs
x.AddDelayedMessageScheduler();
```

Since you already have the service bus message scheduler added.

All you need for the bus configuration:

```cs
x.UsingAzureServiceBus((context, cfg) =>
{
    cfg.Host("Endpoint=sb://{connectionString}");

    cfg.UseServiceBusMessageScheduler();

    cfg.UseTimeout(timeoutConfigurator =>
    {
        timeoutConfigurator.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10);
    });

    cfg.PrefetchCount = 100;
    cfg.ConcurrentMessageLimit = 100;
    cfg.AutoStart = true;

    cfg.ConfigureEndpoints(context);
});
```

And if you want to configure any properties on your receive endpoints, you need to add a callback vs configuring the bus endpoint properties.

```cs
x.AddConfigureEndpointsCallback((context,name,cfg) =>
{
    if (cfg is IServiceBusReceiveEndpointConfigurator sb)
    {
        sb.LockDuration = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
        sb.MaxDeliveryCount = 5;
        sb.DefaultMessageTimeToLive = TimeSpan.FromDays(7);
    }
});
```

Comment: ah, thank you for your help, the app is working as my expected now when I removed as your suggestion. But I have the question that,  I worked with Saga pattern and realize that I must enable the RequiresSession = true, if not it'll throw SessionId exception. So with Routing Slip we don't need to enable the Session, could you help to explain more? Thank you

Comment: There are [plenty of videos](https://youtu.be/EvqJ_0hTAm0) and samples on how to use the session-based saga repository.

Comment: How do we configure the timeout of RequestTimeoutException? Currently the logic code is still running activities but it throws timeout after ~ 10 second - or when I added debugger so long time