# MassTransit RequestClient timming out when response is sent using Azure Service Bus

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azureservicebus, masstransit

I'm developing two Azure Functions.The first one works as a gateway and the second does the proper handling for specific command requests.

To do so I'm trying to use the RequestClient implementation provided by MassTransit.

The gateway AZ Function will work as client and the other one as the commands consumer.

This is the code of the gateway (client) AZ Function

Startup.cs

```
services.AddMassTransitForAzureFunctions(
   x =>
   {
     x.SetKebabCaseEndpointNameFormatter();

     var entryAssembly = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly();
     var assemblies = new[] { entryAssembly }.Union(pluginAssemblies).ToArray(); 

     x.AddConsumers(assemblies);
     x.AddSagaStateMachines(assemblies);
     x.AddSagas(assemblies);
     x.AddActivities(assemblies);                    
    },
    "ServiceBusConnection",
    (context, cfg) =>
    {
      cfg.UseSendFilter(typeof(CommandSendValidationFilter<>), context);
      cfg.UseSendFilter(typeof(SendJwtTokenAppenderFilter<>), context);                    
      cfg.UsePublishFilter(typeof(CommandPublishValidationFilter<>), context);
      cfg.UsePublishFilter(typeof(PublishJwtTokenAppenderFilter<>), context);
      cfg.AutoStart = true;
    });
```

The following code is the class which is in charge of consuming the RequestClient:

```
public class TestHandler : BaseHandler
{
    private readonly IBus _bus;
    private readonly ILogger<TestHandler> _logger;

    public TestHandler(ILogger<TestHandler> logger, IBus bus)
        : base(logger) { _bus = bus; }

    protected override async Task<TestCommand> BuildCommandFromRequestAsync(HttpRequest request, IQueryCollection query, RouteValueDictionary routeData)
    {
        try
        {
            dynamic requestContent = await request.AsExpandoAsync();

            var command = new TestCommand()
            {
                Id = new Guid(requestContent.id),
                Data = requestContent.data
            };
            return command;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Logger.LogError(ex, "Failed to create command from received request");
            throw new RequestDeserializationException("Request cannot be parsed", ex);
        }
    }

    protected override async Task HandleCommandAsync(dynamic commandResponseObject, TestCommand command)
    {
        //Create the request client                        
        var client = _bus.CreateRequestClient<TestCommand>(new Uri("queue:" + CommandsModule.CommandQueueName));

        //wait for the response
        var response = await client.GetResponse<TestCommandResult>(command);

        commandResponseObject.Id = response.Message.Id; ;
        commandResponseObject.ResponseValue = response.Message.ResponseValue;
    }
}
```

On the consumer AZ Function this is the configuration

Startup

```
services.AddMassTransitForAzureFunctions(x =>
                {
                    x.SetKebabCaseEndpointNameFormatter();
                
                    var entryAssembly = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly();
                    var applicationAssembly = typeof(ApplicationModule).Assembly;

                    x.AddConsumers(new[] { entryAssembly, applicationAssembly });
                }, 
                "ServiceBusConnection",
                (context, cfg) => 
                { 
                    cfg.UseConsumeFilter(typeof(ConsumeAuthenticationFilter<>), context);
                    cfg.UseConsumeFilter(typeof(ConsumeValidationFilter<>), context);
                    cfg.AutoStart = true;
                });
```

And the consumer code is the following:

```
public class TestCommandConsumer : IConsumer<TestCommand>
    {
        private readonly ILogger<TestCommandConsumer> _logger;
        private readonly IConsumeContextUserProvider _consumeContextUserProvider;

        public TestCommandConsumer(IConsumeContextUserProvider consumeContextUserProvider, ILogger<TestCommandConsumer> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            _consumeContextUserProvider = consumeContextUserProvider;
        }

        public async Task Consume(ConsumeContext<TestCommand> context)
        {
            var user = _consumeContextUserProvider.GetUser(context);
            var userId = user.GetUserId().Value;

            var request = context.Message;

            await context.RespondAsync<TestCommandResult>(new TestCommandResult
            {
                Id = request.Id,
                ResponseValue = $"User id for command request is {userId}"
            });
        }
```

As a result the client AZ Function is sending the request to the consumer AZ Function and the second is able the successfully process the message and it's sending a response. However the client times out and no response is being received in the client AZ Function.

Any thoughts?

Thansks in advance!

Comment: Did you get a chance to look into this - [so-link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75872694/get-masstransit-requesttimeoutexception-when-using-with-azure-service-bus) and [mass-transit](https://statics.teams.cdn.office.net/evergreen-assets/safelinks/1/atp-safelinks.html).

Answer (score 0):

In the code that you are using the request client that sends requests to "queue:CommandsModule.CommandQueueName" queue,
But by default mass transit uses the address of bus endpoints as reply address.
I have used the below code to configure endpoints for call back and configuring the endpoints by refering [this doc.](https://statics.teams.cdn.office.net/evergreen-assets/safelinks/1/atp-safelinks.html)

```
zp.AddConfigureEndpointsCallback((matter,NA,xyz) =>
{
    if (xyz is IServiceBusReceiveEndpointConfigurator bus)
    {
        bus.LockDuration = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
        bus.MaxDeliveryCount = 5;
        bus.DefaultMessageTimeToLive = TimeSpan.FromDays(7);
    }
});
```

The code which is required rather than message scheduler is as below by reffering this [so-link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75872694/get-masstransit-requesttimeoutexception-when-using-with-azure-service-bus).

```
zp.UsingAzureServiceBus((matter,NA, xyz) =>
{ xyz.Host("Endpoint=bus://{connectionString}");
    xyz.UseServiceBusMessageScheduler();
    xyz.UseTimeout(timeoutConfigurator =>
    {
        timeoutConfigurator.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10);
    });

    xyz.PrefetchCount = 100;
    xyz.ConcurrentMessageLimit = 100;
    xyz.AutoStart = true;
    xyz.ConfigureEndpoints(context);
});
```

Here the mass transit uses address of bus endpoint as reply address by default, but bus endpoint is a dynamic address that is assigned by azure function runtime.
To fix this specification of reply address is required So passed reply address as header and extract it in consumer and use it as reply address. Use the below code below.

```
protected override async Task HandleCommandAsync(dynamic commandResponseObject, TestCommand command)
{                    
    var client = _bus.CreateRequestClient<TestCommand, TestCommandResult>(new Uri("queue:" + CommandsModule.CommandQueueName), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
    var request = new Message<TestCommand>(command, new Dictionary<string, object>
    {
        { "MT-ResponseAddress", $"{_bus.Address.ToUriString()}/{Guid.NewGuid():N}" }
    });
    var response = await client.Request(request);
    commandResponseObject.Id = response.Message.Id; ;
    commandResponseObject.ResponseValue = response.Message.ResponseValue;
}
```